# Zen Coding in ASP.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, emmet

I've installed the Web Essential for VS 2012 and trying out ZenCoding in ASP.net webforms project specifically in .ascx. However, it did not produce any HTML code. For example, this "ul>li*5>lorem3" produced nothing but "ul>li*5>lorem3" on the generated .aspx

Is it possible to use Zen Coding with ASP.net webforms? I can't find any answers to this problem via Google.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have typed "ul>li*5>lorem3" in the .aspx and compiled, expecting the expression to transform into HTML on compile. Zen Coding (aka Emmet) expressions do not compile to HTML when the .aspx is compiled, you must expand the expression yourself by setting the caret at the end of it and pressing Tab.

It will give the following result:

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li>Sit amet, consectetur.</li>
    <li>Adipiscing elit fusce.</li>
    <li>Vel sapien elit.</li>
    <li>In malesuada semper.</li>
</ul>
```

Emmet only works for regular HTML tags though, no support for ASP.NET controls as far as I can see.

More information (not Visual Studio-specific, but Emmet in general): http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/26/goodbye-zen-coding-hello-emmet/